# Opencart performance issue

Tags: opencart

Opencart having performance issue and takes time to load when the number of category is high, currently i am having **250+ categories** and around **5000 products**. anyone help...

Comment: Can you post your server details? OpenCart has been optimised to 4000 orders per day with over 100,000 SKU items.. OpenCart needs DNS Loadbalancing. Cloud Load Balancing... MySQL DB replication.. Cache.. memcache.. CDN.. much can be done..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried any of the [category count removal](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3703)s? That seems to be the answer to most. if not, then a [page cache mod](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3477) is what you need. Note that you will need [vQmod](http://vqmod.com/) to be able to use both of those

Comment: I am not experienced much in opencart,i tried to cache the categories but it is not effective.

Comment: If you install the vQmod system (free) and the category count removal (also free) you should see a noticeable difference. The page cache mod is a bit more extreme however has huge benefits for larger stores (commercial)

Comment: Ya i tried category count removal, and there is noticeable change. Any other method without using the vQmod?

Comment: not really sure why you'd want to not use vQmod to be honest. It takes next to no memory or processing speed off your site load, and is a great addition to your site

Comment: Now i am using **oca category product count removal** with **vQmod** but i am afraid still there is some lagg

Comment: If you're still getting lag after that, you're going to need to invest in a better server or the cache mod. I'm guessing this is running on a shared hosting package?

Answer (score 0):

Test your page at http://gtmetrix.com
Reduce image size and check needed quality.
Check your .htaccess for expireheaders on images and script.
Add last to file:

```
#Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 week"
</FilesMatch>
```

or

```
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/pjpeg "access plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "modification plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 2 week"
```